# How to set PROCHOT to 100°C on Dell G15?

Tags: cpu, windows-11, fan, intel-core-i7

In the Alienware Command Center program I have multiple thermal profiles that I can choose from. They are:

1. Quiet
2. Cool
3. Balanced
4. Performance

The PROCHOT value is different across these profiles. With "Quiet" and "Cool" profiles it is  90°C; with "Balanced" it is 93°C and with "Performance" it is 100°C.

I usually use the Performance profile but I have decided to create a custom profile to use  more aggressive fan curves but the PROCHOT value is set to 93°C for this custom profile.

I tried to change the fan curves in the Performance profile but when I click on Save, it prompts me to choose a name for new custom profile to save the changes to.

How can I use a custom thermal profile and have the PROCHOT value at 100°C?

Performance profile selected:
[image]

Custom profile selected:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to change the PROCHOT offset in Options. A custom value of `0` should restore the PROCHOT to 100°C.

[image: Options PROCHOT offset]

> But you can drop the limit down using TCC offset in BIOS (if you have it) or in ThrottleStop (check "Options" page, it's named "PROCHOT offset", 0 is 100C, 10 is 90 and so on).

Source: [u/T-Troll on r/Alienware post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Alienware/comments/rzbycj/area_51m_alienware_control_center_how_can_i_cap/hrv7h9a/)